# How can I get the updates and Changes in all masters in a Multi-Master Replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, merge-replication, multi-master-replication

I have configured Mysql Ring replication say as Servers A,B,C. I can get the changes and updates in B when I commit the updates in A. I get it in C when I make changes in B. I get updates in A when I make it in A.

My issue is that I cannot get any changes in C when I make changes in A and vice versa. Alternative servers cannot get the updates. Please suggest me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable the parameter under [mysqld] "log-slave-updates" on each server's in my.cnf file.Restart each server and it will start working .That's all :)